# Gathering Database table information?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find below information from the table in tabular format . I can get `Rows Count`, `Column Name` and `Attribute (DataType)`

```
No.Of columns
No.Of Rows Count
Column name
Attribute (DataType)
Min Value
Max Value
Non null count
Distinct count of the column
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you include some working code?

Comment: You can get that with the help of Stored Procedure, you will find a reference link to that over here: [Get SQL Table Information](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/396093/Get-SQL-Server-Table-Information)

Comment: You need two things: metadata about the table, and data from the table. For the first, see the [catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) and for the second just query the table. How you assemble that into a single table is up to you (TSQL, .NET, something else) but nothing here seems to be very complicated so perhaps you can give more specific details of what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of these items can be found in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view, and the rest can be found by querying the table itself. You say you want this data in a tabular format, but many of the items do not 'fit' together. Can you provide a sample of what the result set should look like?

```
-- No.Of columns
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'

-- No.Of Rows Count
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table

--Column name
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'

--Attribute (DataType)
SELECT DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'

--Min Value
SELECT MIN(column_1)
FROM your_table

--Max Value
SELECT MAX(column_1)
FROM your_table

--Non null count
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column_1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_null_count
FROM your_table

--Distinct count of the column
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column_1
```